# Send dictionary to function that does not accept **kwargs?

Tags: python, dictionary, keyword-argument

I just recently have started learning about the wonders of **kwargs but I've hit a stumbling block. Is there a way of sending keywords of a dictionary to a function that does not accept keyword arguments?
Consider the following simple setup:

```
def two(**kwargs):
  return kwargs['second']

def three(**kwargs):
  return kwargs['third']

parameterDict = {}
parameterDict['first'] = 1
parameterDict['second'] = 2
parameterDict['third'] = 3
```

I use some external code that interfaces in the following style:

```
fitObject = externalCode(two, first=1, second=2)
```

The problem is: "externalCode" does not accept **kwargs, so is there a smart way of getting the dictionary information  into an acceptable form?

Also, the different functions take as parameters different subsets of the parameterDict. So, the function "two" might accept the "first" and "second" parameters, it rejects the "third". And "three" accepts all three.

------------------------------------- EDIT -------------------------------------

People have correctly commented that the above code won't fail -- so I've figured out my problem, and I'm not sure if it's worth a repost or not. I was doing something like this:

```
def printHair(**kwargs):
    if hairColor == 'Black':
        print 'Yep!'
    pass

personA = {'hairColor':'blue'}
printHair(**personA)
NameError: global name 'hairColor' is not defined
```

And, apparently the fix is to explicitly include hairColor when defining: printHair(hairColor, **kwargs) in the first place.

Comment: Your example contradicts your statement that `two` might reject `third` as argument. Please provide more accurate examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> def externalCode(two, first=1, second=2):
...     print two, first, second
... 
>>> params = {'two': 9, 'first': 8, 'second': 7}
>>> externalCode(**params)
9 8 7
```

Comment: I assume OP is probably aware of this (having learned about the wonders of **kwargs), but their problem is if the params dict has a `'third'` key in it then the `externalCode` would raise an error about unexpected keyword argument

Comment: I guess the OP needs to provide more clarity in his question. He says "externalCode" doesn't accept kwargs, but this is clearly a misunderstanding, because all Python functions take kwargs. If what he wants is to pull a subset of a dictionary out during the unpacking or something, that's another topic entirely (because unpacking doesn't and won't solve that problem).

Answer (score 1):

[You can use the keyword expansion operator (`**`) to unpack a dictionary into function arguments.](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)

```
fitObject = externalCode(two, **parameterDict)
```

Comment: same problem as other answer, i guess

Answer (score 0):

How about using get

```
def printHair(**kwargs):
#check if hair colour is in kwargs
#if it is not you can set a default, otherwise default is None
   personA['hairColor'] = kwargs.get('hairColor','Blue')
   printHair(**personA)
```